# Apache ScriptAliasMatch to all sub directories ending with _git

Tags: apache-2.2, git

I am trying to match all sub directories under a document root that ends in _git and then divert to the git http cgi scripts

I currently have: `ScriptAliasMatch ^/*/*_git/$ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/`

but this does not work, can anyone advise on the correct syntex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that expanding the match to look for git specific requests it works

```
ScriptAliasMatch "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                info/refs | \
                objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                         [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                         pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                         git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1
```